# Register Multiple Email Output Services using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using the excellent Simple Injector Ioc framework and would like to "plug in" multiple email output services ie Mandrill, MailChimp etc
My question really is am I doing this correctly as it results in a Cast at my send method.

So I have a simple IEmailOutputService

```
public interface IEmailOutputService
{
   string Identifier { get; }
   bool Send(object message, object contents);
}
```

And a MandrillOutputService (shortened)

```
public class MandrillOutputService : IEmailOutputService
{         
   public MandrillOutputService()
   {
     //DI stuff here
   }

   public string Identifier => "Mandrill"; 
   public bool Send(EmailMessage message, IEnumerable<TemplateContent> templateContents)
   {
     if (message == null)
       return false;

     //send code here      
     return true;
   }

  bool IEmailOutputService.Send(object message, object contents)
  {
    //TODO this doesnt look right!!
    var m = message as EmailMessage;
    var c = contents as IEnumerable<TemplateContent>;
    //forwards method onto bespoke Mandrill Send method above
    return Send(m, c);
  }
```

}

I have an `EmailContext` that gets the Email Output Provider for the logged in User eg "Mandrill" heres the IEmailContext

```
public interface IEmailContext
{
  string GetProvider();
}
```

EmailOutputComposite is used to select correct Email Output Service

```
public class EmailOutputComposite : IEmailOutputService
{
  private readonly IEmailContext _emailContext;
  private readonly IEnumerable<IEmailOutputService> _emailOutputServices;
  public string Identifier => "EmailOutputComposite";

  public EmailOutputComposite(
    IEmailContext emailContext, IEnumerable<IEmailOutputService> emailOutputServices)
  {
    this._emailContext = emailContext;
    this._emailOutputServices = emailOutputServices;
  }

  bool IEmailOutputService.Send(object message, object contents) =>
    this._emailOutputServices
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Identifier.ToLower() == this._emailContext.GetProvider())
      .Send(message, contents);
}
```

and finally registrations in Simple Injector

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IEmailOutputService), new[]
{
    typeof(MandrillOutputService)
    //other emailOutputServices to go here
});
container.Register(typeof(IEmailOutputService), typeof(EmailOutputComposite),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

So my question is am I doing this correctly or is there a better way. I have to get the Users Email Provider (Mandrill) from Database so cant think of another way to do this but was concerned with the Cast I have to do in MandrillOutputService.Send method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your design:

1. You are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in your `MandrillOutputService` by accepting only a subset of the accepted types of the `IEmailOutputService` abstraction; this might cause the appliation to break at runtime when the user supplies values that are invalid for that specific implementation.
2. The `Identifier` property on the `IEmailOutputService` violates the [Interface Segration Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), because it is a method that consumers don't use. The only class that is actually interested in this property is the `EmailOutputComposite`. Removing the `Identifier` from the abstraction has the advantage that it can simplify unit testing, since there is less code that a consumer can call. It also simplifies the interface, which is always a good thing.

I'm unsure how to fix the LSP principle, because its unclear to me how other implementations look like.

With respect to the ISP violation, you can do the following to fix it:

- Mark the implementations instead with an attribute that defines their `Identifier`. This allows you to remove the property from the interface, but the downside is that the Composite can only filter those services in case the actual types are injected (and not decorated, because that disallows you from retrieving those attributes).
- You let the Composite depend on the actual concrete implementations and implement a `switch`-`case` statement inside the Composite. This again allows you to remove the property from the interface, but downside is that you will have to update the composite every time a new implementation is added (which might not be that bad if you consider the Composite part of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).
- You define a dictionary of IEmailOutputServices during the registration process, where the `Identifier` is the dictionary's key. This removes the need to have the `Identifier` as part of the abstraction, but also removes the identifier from the implementation (which might actually be something good).

Here's an example of this last example:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IEmailOutputService, EmailOutputComposite>();
container.RegisterSingleton(new Dictionary<string, Func<IEmailOutputService>>()
{
    "Mandrill", CreateEmailServiceProducer<MandrillOutputService>(container),
    "other", CreateEmailServiceProducer<Other>(container),
    //  ..
});

privte static Func<IEmailOutputService> CreateEmailServiceProducer<T>(Container c)
    where T : IEmailOutputService =>
    Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IEmailOutputService, T>(c).GetInstance;
```

Where the Composite is implemented as follows:

```
public class EmailOutputComposite : IEmailOutputService
{
    private readonly IEmailContext _emailContext;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IEmailOutputService>> _emailOutputServices;

    public EmailOutputComposite(
        IEmailContext emailContext, 
        Dictionary<string, Func<IEmailOutputService>> emailOutputServices)
    {
        _emailContext = emailContext;
        _emailOutputServices = emailOutputServices;
    }

    public bool Send(object m, object c) => Service.Send(m, c);
    IEmailOutputService Service => _emailOutputServices[_emailContext.GetProvider()]();
}
```

Whether or not this is actually an improvement is up to you.

Comment: Thank you Steven food for thought there and some good code suggestions I've got a lot to learn regarding composite pattern with container registrations but see the benefits of trying to avoid the run time data problem.

Comment: One more thing, returning bool from your Send is not a good idea. Make it void and throw an exception.

Comment: Will do. With regards to breaking LSP the classes EmailMessage, TemplateContent are Mandrill specific so do you think generics would help there as I will need to substitute those for 'other' email providers classes? thanks

Comment: If those classes are Mandrill specific, it means the consumer needs to be aware of the used implementation as well, while you should strive to hide these details from the consumer. I can't comment on how to do this; you posted too little code for me to get a good overview of the design.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use the Strategy and Factory patterns, forgive me I'm going to change the implementation a bit:

For container registrations:

```
 container.Register<EmailProviderFactory>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
 container.Register<MandrillOutputService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
 container.Register<OtherOutputService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Then use a factory to resolve my email providers:

```
public class EmailProviderFactory
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public EmailProviderFactory(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IEmailOutputService Create(string provider)
    {
        switch (provider)
        {
            case "Mandrill": // should be in a constants class
                return container.GetInstance<MandrillOutputService>();

            case "Other":  // should be in a constants class
                 return container.GetInstance<OtherOutputService>();

            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("provider");
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the IEmailOutputService to have one method with explicit types:

```
public interface IEmailOutputService
{ 
    bool Send(EmailMessage message, IEnumerable<TemplateContent> contents);
}
```

The email providers :

```
public class MandrillOutputService : IEmailOutputService
{
    public bool Send(EmailMessage message, IEnumerable<TemplateContent> templateContents)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class OtherOutputService : IEmailOutputService
{
    public bool Send(EmailMessage message, IEnumerable<TemplateContent> templateContents)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
foreach(var userEmailProvider in UserEmailProviders) {
     // I'm assuming the factory is injected
     var emailService = _emailProviderFactory.Create(userEmailProvider.Name);

     emailService.Send(new EmailMessage(), new List<TemplateContent>());
}
```

I do not think you need `IEmailContext` or a `EmailOutputComposite`. By using the `EmailProviderFactory` you will only create a specific provider when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer which is very interesting as I had thought about using the factory pattern. I'm going to accept Stevens answer as I would like to stick with the Composite class on this occasion

Comment: Great answer. Two comments though. 1. Get rid of the factory abstraction and make it into a proxy implementing IEmailOutputService; factory [is not the right abstraction](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) here. 2. Make sure the concrete types are registered, to allow them to be verified as well.